# Javascript: Get element by class name not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, rich-text-editor

I am working on rich text editor and did well till now. I've made a separate `.js` file to use it as a plugin.

Now i want to use this plugin by giving it a class name through `.cshtml` file.But it doesn't seem to work, i've searched for related answers and they said using `document.getElementsByClassName` will solve my problem.

Please go through this code and tell me what went wrong?

**Text editor .js**-

```
var richTextEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("text-editor");
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.designMode = 'ON';
    $('#strong').live('click', function () {
        richTextEditor.contentDocument.designMode = 'ON';
        richTextEditor.contentDocument.body.contentEditable = true;

        richTextEditor.contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        richTextEditor.focus();
    });
```

**cshtml file-**

```
<script src="/js/Texteditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <div  id="strong" class="command btn"><i class="icon-bold icon-black"></i></div>



    <iframe id="edtNoteCreate" class="text-editor"  name="DisplayNote" style="width:430px;height:150px;">@((Model.Note != null ? Model.Note : ""))</iframe>
```

Comment: [Read the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) `getElementsByClassName` returns more than one element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just take the first item of the matched nodes; it's a NodeList but can be dereferenced like an Array.

```
var richTextEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("text-editor")[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

getElementsByClassName returns an array so use like this

```
 var richTextEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("text-editor");
    richTextEditor[0].contentDocument.designMode = 'ON';
    $('#strong').live('click', function () {
        richTextEditor[0].contentDocument.designMode = 'ON';
        richTextEditor[0].contentDocument.body.contentEditable = true;

        richTextEditor[0].contentDocument.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        richTextEditor[0].focus();
    });
```

Comment: why repeating `[0]` ? give `[0]` when var is declared. :)

Comment: @prasath k, Why it returns an array?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName .. As you see it get ELEMENTS not Element by class name .. If you have 5 elements with same class name then it returns all the five elements with index 0,1,2,3,4,... If you want to get a single element you should go for getElementById()

Comment: @Manoz Because it is class name. You may have given the same class name to many elements in your HTML. Even if you have given the class name to single element, use the same as @PrasathK suggested. and also `live` function of jQuery is deprecated. You should go with `.on()`. check jQuery documentation.

Comment: Upvote for @Mr_Green comment .. I just thought that questioner may have more than one element with same class name so repeated [0].. Anyway i apologise for it

Answer (score 1):

why dont you use jquery methods??

```
var richTextEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("text-editor");

instead try this:

var richTextEditor = $(".text-editor"); //again this is going to return more than  one object.

//so you can also try below code to manipulate in that.

var richTextEditor = $(".text-editor").first(); //for first element. similarly can use .last() or n-th child.
```

Comment: You suggestion is meaningful, But i am using many more `execCommands` for this editor, so giving it child won't help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery, why not stick with jQuery.

```
  var richTextEditor = $('.text-editor').eq(0);
```

and also `live` method of jQuery is deprecated, use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

$(".text-editor") returns HTMl object.
“document.getElementsByClassName("text-editor")”  returns array object.